# Problem while cross communication between a domain opened in an Iframe and opened standalone in a new tab with sharedworker, broadcast channel etc

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web, iframe

I am facing a problem while cross communication between a domain opened in an Iframe and opened standalone in a new tab with sharedworker, broadcast channel and local storage.

=========================

For instance, have a look at the setup below.

Tab 1 (xyz.com)
has an iframe embedded abc.com

Tab 2 (abc.com)

Tab 3 (abc.com)

Tab 4 (xyz.com)
has an iframe embedded abc.com

=========================

What I want is data to be shared across all instances of abc.com

I would refer tab 2 and 3 as standalone and tab 1 and 4 as embedded instances.

The problem is that I cannot get standalone and embedded instances to communicate with either sharedworker or the broadcast channel and not even the browser storage for some reason. But they are the same domain!

Another interesting thing here is the standalone tabs can communicate within each other properly and so can the embedded tabs i.e tab 1 and tab 4 can talk to each other and similarly tab 3 and tab 4 with each other.

I've got a very simple broadcast channel code below that runs in abc.com:

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel("abc-channel");

channel.onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log("on message", e);
};

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(" setInterval running");
  channel.postMessage("custom message");
}, 5000);
```

I am trying to run this in chrome v117.0.5938.149 in Ventura macOs 13.6

I suspect this is an issue with some recent update in chrome because I had it working on an earlier version as it should.

Any help would be appreciated.

==================================

UPDATE

I deployed two websites to demonstrate the above.

website with broadcast channel code (https://github.com/prateekinfi/broadcast-demo-1)
https://broadcastdemo-1.netlify.app/

[App 1 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p7ee.png)

website with embedded app1 (https://github.com/prateekinfi/broadcast-demo-2)
https://broadcastdemo-2.netlify.app/

[App 2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtEjj.png)

====================================

UPDATE

Found a thread with a similar problem : [Are browsers now blocking access to localStorage inside of cross origin iframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283548/are-browsers-now-blocking-access-to-localstorage-inside-of-cross-origin-iframes)

As this post suggests, I can also get things to work in firefox if I set cookie blocking to only "Cross-site tracking cookies" instead of "Cross-site tracking cookies, and isolate other cross-site cookies" (under about:preferences#privacy)

==================================

UPDATE

I found the root cause - Storage Partitioning
https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/storage-partitioning/

Really disappointed with this, it can be a breaking change for a lot of web-apps. :(

Comment: The origin for all the pages (and frames etc) has to be **exactly** the same, not simply the same domain. They all have to be `http:` or `https:`, they have to hav the same port and the same host name (not simply the same IP address).

Comment: And it is the same - its https://

Comment: From your description it would appear that the tab container element is NOT abc.com thus those children cannot communicate with each other via that parent in a differing domain. FWIW I will not visit random site links embedded within a post I do not recognize for various reasons.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Are you absolutely sure it works like that? I could not find any documentation that lists down this restriction (of the parent tab having to be the same domain)

Comment: Well just to clear out one point. What do you mean by "communicate with each other via that parent"? Both the abc.com instances instantiate a broadcast channel to communicate. At least that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Anything NOT using the parent element will have to do so via the server in some manner like ajax etc.

Comment: Some searching can find possible useful information or duplicates here. Several others...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73444659/cross-tab-communication-between-iframe-and-different-tab-in-safari?rq=2
https://stackoverflow.com/q/27234528/125981
https://stackoverflow.com/q/4079280/125981
https://stackoverflow.com/q/28230845/125981
https://stackoverflow.com/q/1366483/125981

Comment: Also by "tab" do you me elements on a page as a visual "tab" or new windows in the browser - docked as tabs - I was thinking the first on my initial comment

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I meant a google chrome tab running abc.com and another google chrome tab running xyz.com with an iframe of abc.com embedded. Thanks for the resource links, although none of those worked out for me.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I added some image links towards the end, although I don't know if you would trust those or not :D

Comment: Reading about Browsing contexts, I think what I'm expecting is reasonable

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Browsing_context

Comment: I think this post is very close/ exactly the issue that I'm mentioning - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283548/are-browsers-now-blocking-access-to-localstorage-inside-of-cross-origin-iframes



"This has been working just fine but recently has stopped working because a.com does not have access to localStorage when loaded inside the iframe. "

Comment: I found it https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/storage-partitioning/

Comment: @prateekinfi thank you for that! Time-wise Chrome version 115 roll-out does correlate with the issues we suddenly started seeing with BroadcastChannel suddenly & randomly not working for our users. In our product we have an iFrame which opens a new window, both from 1:1 same origin, and BroadcastChannel doesn't work any more. Same thing works well in Edge and other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Storage Access API`.

Efforts are being made to extend `SAA` to storage and communication APIs.

In short, the idea is to allow unpartitioned access to partitioned APIs securely, upon user gesture.

You can find the full explanation for whether or not a third-party context will go unpartitioned here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API#how_it_works

Given you have decided you are interested in trying, you should register for the [Origin Trial](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/origin-trials): https://developer.chrome.com/origintrials/#/view_trial/577023702256844801

`localStorage` is available from **Chrome 120**, and `BroadcastChannel` from **Chrome 121**.
[It is not promised](https://arichiv.github.io/saa-non-cookie-storage/#shareddedicated-workers) that SharedWorker will be included in this solution.

If you are not familiar with Origin Trials, I strongly recommend reading through the link I shared above.

Check out the following explainer that includes code examples: https://arichiv.github.io/saa-non-cookie-storage/#use-cases