# Are browsers now blocking access to localStorage inside of cross origin iframes?

Tags: http, iframe, local-storage

We use an iframe set up to allow cross domain persistent login. The flow is as follows.

```
- Log in to https://a.com
    * an authentication token is stored in localStorage
- Go to https://b.com
    * An iframe for https://a.com/getToken is loaded
    * A window.addEventListener('message', (message) => {...}) message listener is created
    * in the iframe a.com gets the token that is stored in localStorage
    * a.com uses window.parent.postMessage() to send the token to the b.com parent
```

This has been working just fine but recently has stopped working because a.com does not have access to localStorage when loaded inside the iframe. I can get things to work in firefox if I set cookie blocking to only "Cross-site tracking cookies" instead of "Cross-site tracking cookies, and isolate other cross-site cookies" (under about:preferences#privacy). I haven't been able to find a setting configuration that works in chromium browsers.

Does anyone know if there is a combination of headers we can use that would allow this functionality? Or is this a design pattern that no longer works?

Comment: I have the same problem. From what I read so far, the Storage Access API is pretty much useless for Chrome (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API and https://github.com/GoogleChrome/related-website-sets/). Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problems with Broadcast channel and shared worker as well.

[Problem while cross communication between a domain opened in an Iframe and opened standalone in a new tab with sharedworker, broadcast channel etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77273432/problem-while-cross-communication-between-a-domain-opened-in-an-iframe-and-opene)

This problem seems to have come up recently.

I could also make the broadcast channel work in firefox with the cookie setting change you suggested

========================

UPDATE

I found the root cause - Storage Partitioning https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/storage-partitioning/

Comment: Thanks! Have you had success using the storage access API? I've been trying it out but can't get the browsers to show a prompt after clicking a button in the iframe.